# Find the same values in another column in matlab

Tags: matlab, unique

i want to find same values of number in different column,
for example i have a matrix array:

```
A = [1  11  0.17
2   1   78
3   4   90
45  5   14
10  10  1]
```

so as you can see no. 1 in column 1 have the same values in column 2 and column 3, so i want to pick that number and put into another cell or matrix cell

```
B= [1]
```

and perform another operation C/B, letting C is equal to:

```
C= [1
3
5
7
9]
```

and you will have:

```
D= [1   11  0.17    1
2   1   78  3
3   4   90  5
45  5   14  7
10  10  1   9]
```

then after that, values in column 4 have equivalent numbers that we can define, but we will choose only those number that have number 1, or B in theirs row

define:

```
1-->23
3 -->56
9 --> 78
```

then we have, see image below:
[image]

so how can i do that? is it possible? thanks

Comment: I'm confused... and I also have several questions.  I don't quite understand your English so please excuse any misunderstandings.  (1) Do you want to find a value that appears **in all columns** of your matrix?  (2) Your example only showed one value in common with all columns.  What if you had more than one value?  What are you supposed to do then?  (3) I don't understand the `C / B` bit.  I don't get how doing `C / B` results in the fourth column of the matrix.  (4) How did you get the `23, 56, 78` mapping?  That also doesn't make any sense.

Comment: (1.) yes, (2.) assume that there's only one unique or same values on each columns, (3)  you divide C over B,  (4), you define it.

Comment: sorry i will edit again my problem

Comment: No problem.  That makes more sense now.  So am I to assume that all columns will have either **one** value that's shared among all columns or none?

Comment: yes only one, please use my example data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's tackle your problem into steps.

## Step #1 - Determine if there is a value shared by all columns

We can do this intelligently by [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html), [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) and [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) and [`all`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html).

We first need to use `unique` so that we can generate all possible unique values in the matrix `A`.  Once we do this, we can look at each value of the unique values and see if all columns in `A` contain this value.  If this is the case, then this is the number we need to focus on.

As such, do something like this first:

```
Aun = unique(A);
eqs_mat = bsxfun(@eq, A, permute(Aun, [3 2 1]));
```

`eqs_mat` would generate a 3D matrix where each slice figures out where a particular value in the unique array appeared.  As such, for each slice, each column will have a bunch of `false` values but at least one `true` value where this true value tells you the position in the column that matched a unique value.  The next thing you'll want to do is go through each slice of this result and determine whether there is at least one non-zero value for each column.

For a value to be shared along all columns, a slice should have a non-zero value per column.

We can eloquently determine which value we need to extract by:

```
ind = squeeze(all(any(eqs_mat,1),2));
```

Given your example data, we have this for our unique values:

```
>> B

B =

    0.1700
    1.0000
    2.0000
    3.0000
    4.0000
    5.0000
   10.0000
   11.0000
   14.0000
   45.0000
   78.0000
   90.0000
```

Also, the last statement I executed above gives us:

```
>> ind

ind =

     0
     1
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
     0
```

The above means that the second location of the unique array is the value we want, and this corresponds to `1`.  Therefore, we can extract the particular value we want by:

```
val = Aun(ind);
```

`val` contains the value that is shared along all columns.

## Step #2 - Given the value `B`, take a vector `C` and divide by `B`.

That's pretty straight forward.  Make sure that `C` is the same size as the total number of rows as `A`, so:

```
C = [1 3 5 7 9].';
B = val;
col = C / B;
```

## Step #3 - For each location in `A` that shares the common value, we want to generate a new fifth column that gives a new value for each corresponding row.

You can do that by declaring a vector of... say... zeroes, then find the right rows that share the common value and replace the values in this fifth column with the values you want:

```
zer = zeros(size(A,1), 1);
D = [23; 56; 78];
ind2 = any(A == val, 2);
zer(ind2) = D;

%// Create final matrix
fin = [A col zer];
```

We finally get:

```
>> fin

fin =

    1.0000   11.0000    0.1700    1.0000   23.0000
    2.0000    1.0000   78.0000    3.0000   56.0000
    3.0000    4.0000   90.0000    5.0000         0
   45.0000    5.0000   14.0000    7.0000         0
   10.0000   10.0000    1.0000    9.0000   78.0000
```

Take note that you need to make sure that what you're assigning to the fifth column **is the same size** as the total number of columns in `A`.